# Relationship issue in an ERD

Tags: database, database-design

I have created a simple ERD for a cultural site. Are these relationships correct?

cul_categories ( ||-----|<- ) cul_pages // Travel has at least one page

cul_categories ( ||-----O-<- ) sub_categories //e.g Arts---->Music, painting etc. ,or there can be, for example, a Travel which has no sub-category.

sub_categories ( ||-----|<- ) cul_pages // if we have Music then at least one page for it.

[image]

Comment: I don't have a drawing tool either.  Your relationships are consistent.  Only you can tell us if they accurately map the data you want to save (are correct).  You might want to consider just having a cul_categories with a value that determines if the category has a parent (is a sub category).

Comment: i mean to say if the page only belongs to cul_categories then the composite foreign key in cul_pages, for instance, in a row will have the value for cul_category_id but null for sub_category_id. Is it fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to be sure if it's correct, but there is a problem. You cannot enforce the rules about "pages" being in EITHER a category OR a subcategory, because you can't make the foreign key columns not-null.

To avoid this, you could change the model as follows:

```
TABLE: Category
-------------------
CategoryID (PK)
ParentCategoryID (FK)
Name

TABLE: Page
--------------
PageID (PK)
CategoryID (FK)
...
```

This allows you to create a NOT NULL foreign key relationship from Page to Category; categories with a NULL ParentCategoryID are "top level" categories, and categories with a parentCategoryID are subcategories.

Sample data:

```
Category

CategoryID    ParentCategory    Name
-----------------------------------------
1             null              Arts
2             1                 Painting
3             1                 Music
4             null              Travel


Page

PageID    CategoryID        Name
-------------------------------------
1         2                 Page about painting
2         3                 Page about music
3         3                 Another page about music
4         4                 Page about travel
```

Comment: but what if a top level category doesn't have a sub-category but a page?

Comment: Then your Page table has a CategoryID value linking to the top level category. I've added some sample data to explain.

Comment: Much better. Thanks Neville